# TDD and configuration variables

Tags: configuration, tdd, configuration-files

I'm learning TDD (in Javascript), and I wanted to know, what is the right way to use configuration variables? Should I make a separate class and have them be member variables of the class, and pass an instance of the class to every object that needs it, or make a list of global variables and just use those? What are the benefits / setbacks of each method?

For example, I have to get data from a URL as follows:

```
function getData (remoteDataDelegate) {
    remoteDataDelegate.getData(userInfoURL)
}
```

where `userInfoURL` is a configuration variable that I set elsewhere to the URL for a page on my site.

Comment: What do you mean by "configuration variables"?  Please provide a (very short) example of the kind of code you're trying to test.

Comment: When you edit the question, please look at the right side of the page.  Please read the instructors for formatting code.  Then, please format your code according to those instructions so that it looks like code.

Comment: By "configuration variable" you mean "global variable"?

Comment: @S.Lott: That's weird, I thought I had formatted it correctly, but I guess something went wrong. I have edited the question again.

And yes, I mean "global variable". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of how I do it:

```
function NewConfiguration() {
    var config = {};
    config.carriersSelector = NewCarriersSelector();
    config.paymentMethodsSelector = NewPaymentMethodsSelector();

    return config;
}
```

Usage:

```
function NewOrderModel(request, searchRequest) {
    var configuration = NewConfiguration();
    // ... other variables code
var that = {
    getContentSuccess: function(cb) {
        // .. setup code

        $.ajax({
            type:       'GET',
            url:        request.page,
            dataType:   'json',
            data:       request.data,
            async:      request.async,
            success:    function(data) {
                if (data.status === 'success') {
                    cb(data.html, activeCustomer, step, configuration);
                }
                if (data.status == 'flash') {
                    flash(data.flash);
                }
            },
            complete:   request.complete
        });
    },

}
```

You will notice that the configuration is not being injected. for me, in this sample code the configuration never changes. Now my request objects change so they get injected, so I can mock those out or redirect the pages.

Answer (score 0):

Global variables are usually set by the setUp method of your TestCase.